# TclError: can't iconify: override-redirect flag is set

Tags: python, tkinter, root

I am working on a project where I got rid of the root window. And I made my own. I have it working but I have not been able to find out a way to minimize the window.

I tried using `root.iconify()` with `root.root.overrideredirect(True)` set. But it gives me the following error: `TclError: can't iconify ".": override-redirect flag is set`.

How can I minimize the window without getting this error and where it minimizes it like a normal root window.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import os

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
       Frame.__init__(self,parent)
       self.pack(fill=BOTH)

       self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.borderFrame = Frame(self, width=500, height=600, bg="Gray")
        self.borderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.borderFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.holderFrame = Frame(self.borderFrame, width=500, height=570, bg="blue")
        self.holderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.holderFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.close = Label(self, font=("Arial", 11), bg="Gray", anchor=CENTER, text="X", cursor="hand2")
        self.close.place(x=460, y=0, width=40, height=30)

        self.min = Label(self, font=("Arial", 11), bg="Gray", anchor=CENTER, text="_", cursor="hand2")
        self.min.place(x=420, y=0, width=40, height=30)

        def hoverMin(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="lightBlue")

        def unHoverMin(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="Gray")

        self.min.bind("<Enter>", hoverMin)
        self.min.bind("<Leave>", unHoverMin)
        self.min.bind("<Button-1>", self.minimize)

        def hover(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="red")

        def unhover(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="Gray")

        self.close.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        self.close.bind("<Leave>", unhover)
        self.close.bind("<Button-1>", self.exitProgram)

        self.borderFrame.bind("<Button-1>", self.startMove)
        self.borderFrame.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopMove)
        self.borderFrame.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.moving)

    def startMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def stopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def moving(self,event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.borderFrame.winfo_rootx() + self.borderFrame.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.borderFrame.winfo_rooty() + self.borderFrame.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))

    def minimize(self, event):
        root.iconify()

    def exitProgram(self, event):
        os._exit(0)

root = Tk()
root.title("Draggable Root")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.overrideredirect(True)

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a **simple** working example that we can run to see if we have the same problem?

Comment: @Rinzler Sorry I took so long to edit I had no wifi. But I edited can you check it out?

Comment: My guess is that you cannot _iconify_ the window when _overrideredirect_ flag is set to non zero-values. But you should keep searching to find a solution or wait for an answer, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling overrideredirect(True) declares to the window manager that you will handle all of your own window-management.  Iconification is a window-manager thing.  If you just want to hide the window, then changing the minimize function to root.state('withdrawn') does that.  Call root.state('normal') to show the window again.

In order to appear in the taskbar, you need to call root.overrideredirect(False) before you call root.state('iconic')  AND BEFORE THAT you need to call root.update_idletasks().  See the change to the minimize method.

In order to get the window back the way you want, I made a new method 'frame_mapped' and bound it to the Map event on the borderFrame.  Map events happen when a widget gets handled by the geometry manager ( pack/place/grid).  So that when you click on the taskbar to un-minimize, 'frame_mapped' gets triggered to call overrideredirect(True) again.

Here is the modified code:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

import time
import os

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
       Frame.__init__(self,parent)
       self.pack(fill=BOTH)

       self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.borderFrame = Frame(self, width=500, height=600, bg="Gray")
        self.borderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.borderFrame.pack(side=TOP)

        self.holderFrame = Frame(self.borderFrame, width=500, height=570, bg="blue")
        self.holderFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.holderFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.close = Label(self, font=("Arial", 11), bg="Gray", anchor=CENTER, text="X", cursor="hand2")
        self.close.place(x=460, y=0, width=40, height=30)

        self.min = Label(self, font=("Arial", 11), bg="Gray", anchor=CENTER, text="_", cursor="hand2")
        self.min.place(x=420, y=0, width=40, height=30)

        def hoverMin(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="lightBlue")

        def unHoverMin(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="Gray")

        self.min.bind("<Enter>", hoverMin)
        self.min.bind("<Leave>", unHoverMin)
        self.min.bind("<Button-1>", self.minimize)

        def hover(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="red")

        def unhover(event):
            event.widget.config(bg="Gray")

        self.close.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        self.close.bind("<Leave>", unhover)
        self.close.bind("<Button-1>", self.exitProgram)

        self.borderFrame.bind("<Button-1>", self.startMove)
        self.borderFrame.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stopMove)
        self.borderFrame.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.moving)

        self.borderFrame.bind("<Map>",self.frame_mapped)

    def startMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def stopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def moving(self,event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.borderFrame.winfo_rootx() + self.borderFrame.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.borderFrame.winfo_rooty() + self.borderFrame.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))

    def frame_mapped(self,e):
        print(self,e)
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.overrideredirect(True)
        root.state('normal')


    def minimize(self, event):
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.overrideredirect(False)
        #root.state('withdrawn')
        root.state('iconic')

    def exitProgram(self, event):
        os._exit(0)

root = Tk()
root.title("Draggable Root")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.overrideredirect(True)

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if I call root.state("withdrawn") will it still show up on the task bar?

Comment: No, unfortunately it will not.  You need to not be in overrideredirect(True) mode.  See my edit above for the solution, which is to switch off the override when you minimize, and then bind to the '<Map>' event which gets called when the window gets displayed, in order to switch override back on.